# Mi programa se cierra cuando lo abro (a pesar de usar std::cin y abrirlo desde cmd)

Tags: c++

Terminé hace poco un curso en Codecademy y por curiosidad intenté hacer un programa que sirva para jugar "Tres en raya", "Tatetí" o "Tic-Tac-Toe". Sin embargo el programa se cierra, lo abra como ejecutable o lo abra desde una consola ya abierta. Adjunto el código de los tres archivos: `main.cpp`, `fns.cpp` y `fns.hpp`.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "fns.hpp"

int main(){
    board game1;
    int xaxis, yaxis;
    char player;

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        
        if(i%2==0){
            player = 'X';
        }else{
            player = 'O';
        }

        std::cout << "X:";
        std::cin >> xaxis;
        std::cout << "Y:";
        std::cin >> yaxis;

        game1.set(xaxis, yaxis, player, i);
        std::cout << game1.state();
        if(game1.win() == true){
            std::cout << "And the winner is... " << game1.winner;
        }

    }
    std::cout << "That's a tie!";
}
```

`fns.hpp`:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    
    class board{
        std::vector<std::vector<char>> space;
    
    public:
        char winner;
        board();
        void set(int x, int y, char symbol, int &ref_i);
        std::string state();
        bool win();
    };
```

`fns.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "fns.hpp"

board::board(){
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        space[i][0] = ' ';
        space[i][1] = ' ';
        space[i][2] = ' ';
    }
}

void board::set(int x, int y, char symbol, int &ref_i){
    if(space[x][y] == ' '){
        space[x][y] = symbol;
    }else{
        std::cout << "This place is already occupied :(";
        ref_i--;
    }
}

bool board::win(){
    
    //Vertical
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(space[i][0] == space[i][1] && space[i][1] == space[i][2]){
            winner = space[i][0];
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    //Horizontal
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        if(space[0][i] == space[1][i] && space[1][i] == space[2][i]){
            winner = space[0][i];
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    //Diagonal
    if(space[0][0] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[2][2]){
        winner = space[0][0];
        return true;
    }
    if(space[2][0] == space[1][1] && space[1][1] == space[0][2]){
        winner = space[2][0];
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

std::string board::state(){
    std::string temp = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        temp = temp + space[0][i] + space[1][i] + space[2][i] + " \n ";
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los contenedores `std::vector`, por defecto, están vacíos, no tienen elementos. Además, el operador `[]` no permite crear elementos en el contenedor.

Si juntas estas dos circunstancias entonces tienes que tu clase `board` tiene tendencia a acceder a posiciones no válidas de `space`. Por ejemplo en el constructor:

```
board::board(){
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        space[i][0] = ' '; // <<--- AQUI
        space[i][1] = ' '; // <<--- AQUI
        space[i][2] = ' '; // <<--- AQUI
    }
}
```

Para inicializar correctamente `space` debes crear, manualmente, las posiciones que te interesan:

```
board::board(){
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        space.push_back({' ', ' ', ' '});
    }
}
```